# Facebook integration error with gradle

Tags: android

I am using android studio 2.3.3 with a compiledSdkVersion 26. I got error when trying to build a gradle with com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5) that shows red line in 'com.android.support:app compact-v7:26.+' . How can i fix it or what else i need to add in a gradle file. 
[Click the link here for the build.gradle file which shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAwgJ.jpg)

Comment: add specific persion of the api rather than + mark

Answer (score 0):

the solution which worked for me is that i changed all my compiled dependencies to a specific version not something like you have v7.26.+ .
Change it to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta1'
```

hope this will help.

Comment: I changed both the compiled dependencies in a gradle file. It said  failed to resolve 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta1'

Comment: have you deleted the existing ones ?

Comment: if yes , than make sure that from SDK manager, you have both the Android Support Repository and Google Repository installed and up to date.

Comment: Yes I have both Android Support Repository and Google Repository installed and up to date.

Comment: These are the error messages > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.24.0